# What's the default weight of a form's submit element?

Tags: forms

The following code is fairly standard for adding a submit button to the bottom of a form:

```
// Submit button.
$form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save'),
);
```

It always appears at the bottom of the form so I assume it is assigned a 'heavy' #weight by default. Does anyone know its default value?

Answer (score 7):

A submit button appears at the bottom of the form usually because it's simply added last in the form definition.

A submit button can still be placed anywhere and weighted using the `#weight` property.

The default weight is assigned automatically.

The relevant core code is in

[`form_builder`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_builder/7)

```
// Assign a decimal placeholder weight to preserve original array order.
if (!isset($element[$key]['#weight'])) {
  $element[$key]['#weight'] = $count/1000;
}
else {
  // If one of the child elements has a weight then we will need to sort
  // later.
  unset($element['#sorted']);
}
```

If not present the`#weight` property is calculated dynamically based on the count/item position while looping over the form element set.